# Type constraint for function type, allowing it to be called with tupled hlist

Tags: scala, shapeless

I would like to create a function defined like this:

```
def applyWithHList[FunctionType, HListType <: HList]
    (func: FunctionType, hlist: HListType) = func.tupled(hlist.tupled)
```

but of course I need some constraint on `FunctionType`.

How can I do it? If it is even possible...

**@Edit:**

I've found [Shapeless Generic](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes) and it is acceptable, but maybe there is solution for the original problem.